# "libmtp error : could not send object info." on attempting to access/transfer files from android phone's memory card

Tags: mtp

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Whenever I try to copy/paste content from/to my Android phone's memory card, I get this error:

```
libmtp Error : Could not send object info.
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if you have solved this but I came across the same issues today.
I was trying to copy music to my Android's phone SD card and I got this error when the file name of the song, not the tag, had 'illegal' symbols in it. I removed the apostrophe and the file copied over.
**05 Goodbye 70's.flac** change to **05 Goodbye 70s.flac**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please include how did you remove the apostrophe.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Geoffrey.  I bumped into the same problem with the filename. For me the 'illegal character was the colon ':' character. The filename which caused the problem was '**Disc 1 - 11 - The Narcotic Suite: 3 Kilos.ogg**', renaming the file to '**Disc 1 - 11 - The Narcotic Suite 3 Kilos.ogg**' ensured that the file could be copied.

I used the 'Files' app to rename the file, right-click on the filename and choose the 'rename' option.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the filename issue mentioned above, another possible reason is that the file to be copied is too big for the MTP device. For example, I get this error when I try to copy a 5GB movie to a SD card, which seems not accepting such large file.

Answer (score 1):

Try compressing it and then copy-pasting it.
It worked when I tried copying ~11 GB zip file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing all the 0000 embedded file .config files from the Android mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I  solved this problem by using another USB cable.
Copy files from Ubuntu 18.04 to Android 14 device.